# Linked List reversal algorithm not working

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to write a simple function that reverses a linked list in Python:

```
def reverse(head):
    prev = None
    nxt = head.next
    head.next = prev
    while nxt:
        prev = head
        head = nxt
        head.next = prev
        nxt = nxt.next
    return head
```

The logic seemed fine when I thought through it.:
First move prev to head, then shuffle head forward so it points to the same node as nxt, before setting head.next to where it was. Finally moving nxt forward by one. Iterate until nxt reaches the end of the list.

However when I tried to reverse a linked list 0->1->2->3->4->5 with the following code:

```
def traverse(head):
    while head:
        print(head.val)
        head = head.next
```

it repeatedly printed 0 and 1 endlessly.

Comment: head=nxt, then you change head.next which also changes nxt.next at which point you lose the information which is the actually next element to reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael pointed out, your code makes first and the second element in the linked list to point to each other.

The fix is pretty simple, here is what I did:

```
def reverse(head):
    nxt = head.next
    head.next = None
    while nxt:
        temp1 = nxt.next
        temp2 = head
        head = nxt 
        nxt.next = temp2
        nxt = temp1
```

This code initially initially does the same thing as yours. The while loop however, uses 2 temporary variables `temp1` and `temp2` to hold the addresses of the variables surrounding `nxt` (on either sides). This prevents the conflict that happened in your code.

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In the while-loop:

```
head = nxt   # head and nxt now refer to the same node
head.next = prev   # head.next now points to previous node but nxt.next does as well
nxt = nxt.next   # this is same as: nxt = head.next  therefore same as: nxt = prev
```